# angularjs ajax results parse error after successfully sending data to php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, angularjs

I have a angular app using jquery for the ajax (I made a little more progress with this issue using jquery for it over $http). I am trying to send json data to php and doing it successfully (php reads it and returns the data through the header). My problem here is $.ajax is failing to recognize a success, it fails and returns parse error for the response.

Here is my javascript:

```
    function loginUser() {
        var target = "../data/user.php";
        var data = {
            "userName": "me",
            "userPass": "pass",
            "action": "login"
        };


        $.ajax({
            url: target,
            type: "POST",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
            alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
        });
    }
```

Here is my php:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
$objData = json_decode($data);
print_r($objData);
```

Here is the response I get in the header from php:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [userName] => me
    [userPass] => pass
    [action] => login
)
```

Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: Why are you using `$.ajax` use Angular's `$http` https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Comment: If you set the proper header you won't need to use `php://input` either.  If you set the header to `Content-Type: application/x-www.form-urlencoded` you can just use the regular php variables ($_GET,$_POST,$_REQUEST) on the other end.  If you're sending a JS object just use jQuery's param function when sending -> `$.param(data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function loginUser($scope,$http,$log) {
    var target = "../data/user.php";
    var data = {
        "userName": "me",
        "userPass": "pass",
        "action": "login"
    };

    $http.post(target,$.param(data),{headers:{'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}}).then(function(response){
        // success stuff here
    },function(response){
        // failed stuff here
        $log.log(response);
    });

}
```

Then in your PHP file you can refer to your data using the $_POST var.

```
$user = array(
    'username' => $_POST['userName'],
    'password' => $_POST['password'],
    'action' => $_POST['action']
);
echo json_encode($user);
```

OR

```
echo json_encode($_POST);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response, I got a successful response finally from angular. the only thing left now is that I cant figure out a way that angular wants to parse json. I have tried the fromJson() but couldnt break it down to individual values from it (eg. response[0].username (throws an error undefined), response.username (undefined no error))

Comment: Try outputting the response to the console so you can see what objects are available.  You should be able to just refer to the object using dot notation just like any other JS object.  If you don't see what you're looking for try outputting response.data to the console.

Answer (score 0):

That response is not valid JSON, thus you get a parse error.  If the client expects JSON and you send it a PHP variable dump, it will not know how to parse it.

Frankly I don't understand what your code is supposed to be doing. It looks like you are trying to mirror back the sent data in the request.

Comment: at the moment I am trying to get a successful communication going both ways. One step at a time.

Comment: @user2174484 Just keep in mind if the client is expecting JSON you need to send back JSON.  You could just do something like `echo json_encode(array('test'));` to test the response.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use $apply() to apply jQuery ajax results on Angular scopes.